# missing separator error in a makefile when adding extra space inside foreach

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

```
THIS_MAKE := $(word $(words $(MAKEFILE_LIST)), $(MAKEFILE_LIST))
MAKER := $(MAKE) -f $(THIS_MAKE)

FILE_LIST=tmp/file tmp/dir/file

all:
 rm -rf tmp
 $(MAKER) copy_files

copy_files: $(FILE_LIST)

tmp/file: | tmp
 echo hello>$@

tmp/dir/file: | tmp/dir
 echo world>$@

define dst_dir_rule
$(1):
 -mkdir -p $$@

endef
$(foreach dir,$(dir $(FILE_LIST)), $(eval $(call dst_dir_rule,$(dir))))

#end of makefile
```

The makefile above should create the files in the FILE_LIST variable.
The problem is with the part that tries to automatically generate rules for the directories.
When I run it I get a "missing separator." error.
When I delete the space between the comma and the $(eval) it works.

I would really like to understand why.

Thanks,
Gur

Comment: After replacing the space in front of the make recipe lines with tab (which anomaly I assume comes from copy & paste) including in front of `-mkdir -p $$@` in the `dst_dir_rule` function, I did not have any problem running this make file. I am using GNU make version 3.81 (as shipped with Ubuntu 12.04).

Answer (score 3):

This is because you need to use tab symbol as command separator in your macro. As you don't have one it yields "missing separator" error.

Fix (using ; command separator on the same line):

```
define dst_dir_rule
$(1): ; -mkdir -p $$@ # as a one liner
```

You can also simplify:

```
THIS_MAKE := $(word $(words $(MAKEFILE_LIST)), $(MAKEFILE_LIST))
```

to:

```
THIS_MAKE := $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))
```

Comment: Thanks for the one liner rule tip. I don't think that this is the problem though since it works without the space. I use ancient "make" at work that doesn't support lastword. I tried to reproduce it at home with a newer make and it worked with and without the space so perhaps it is some old make bug that was fixed since.

Comment: Nope, it did not work with make 3.81 until I made the change.